# Finding point of rotation in the sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I am trying to locate the point of rotation in a sorted array through a modified binary search.

Consider this array `int values[9]={7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`
The point of rotation here is at index = 3 i.e at 9.

I wrote this function for the above operation.

```
void FindRotationPoint(int values[], int numvalues)
{
    int first =0;
    int last = numvalues-1;
    int middle;
    bool moreTosearch= (first<=last);
    while(first<=last)
    {
        middle = (first+last)/2;
        if(values[0]>values[middle]) //Keep looking right if the middle value in array is greater than first
        {
            last = middle-1;
        }
        if (values[0]<values[middle]) //Keep looking left if the middle value in array is less than first
        {
            first = middle+1;
        }
    }
    cout<<middle+1<<endl;
    cout<<values[middle];
}
```

If the elements are
`int values[9]={7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};` **Output: 4, 1** (Wrong)

`int values[9]={7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};` **Output: 4, 10** (Correct)

The point of rotation which is at an even place is found correct whereas in the other case, it finds the succeeding element. What am I missing in the above code?

Comment: Since moreTosearch is always just (fist<=last), perhaps you should remove it and put first<=last in while condition. It would make things both more compact and easier to read.

Comment: Also, this may not work if there are duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
void FindRotationPoint(int values[], int numvalues)
{
    int first =0;
    int last = numvalues-1;
    int middle=0;
    bool moreTosearch= (first<=last);
    while(first<last)
    {
        middle = (first+last)/2;
        if(values[first]>=values[middle]) //Keep looking right if the middle value in array is greater than first
        {
            last = middle;
            cout<<"first>middle: "<<first<<" "<<middle<<" "<<last<<"\n";
        }
        else if (values[middle]>=values[last]) //Keep looking left if the middle value in array is less than first
        {
            first = middle;
            cout<<"middle<last: "<<first<<" "<<middle<<" "<<last<<"\n";
        }
    }
    cout<<middle+1<<endl;
    cout<<values[middle];
}

int main()
{
int values[9]={7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

FindRotationPoint(values, 9);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code have a bug. Its not working for {1, 2, 3, 4}; and also for {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

Comment: It's been a while, I do not remember what I did anymore. Please edit the program if you have a fix. Thanks for pointing out the bug though!

Answer (score 0):

```
void FindRotationPoint(int values[], int numvalues)
{
    int first =0;
    int last = numvalues-1;
    int middle;
    bool moreTosearch= (first<=last);
    while(moreTosearch)
    {
        middle = (first+last)/2;
        if(middle == first) break;
        if(values[0]>values[middle]) //Keep looking right if the middle value in array is greater than first
        {
            last = middle;
            moreTosearch= (first<=last);
        }
        if (values[0]<values[middle]) //Keep looking left if the middle value in array is less than first
        {
            first = middle;
            moreTosearch= (first<=last);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work .

Comment: Using this array at input 'int values[9]={7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};'
Output comes to be 3, 9 which is not the correct answer.

Comment: check again :: 3,9 is for case 1 and 4,10 is for case 2 . Its working !!

Comment: Umm...yeah! It is working. I didn't notice other changes. Could you please explain why `last=middle`, `first=middle` and `if (middle=first) break;` were done?

Comment: I suggest you look up binary search , in brief -- binary search reduces range by 2 ie: (first,last) -> (first,middle) or (middle,last) , if suppose you get x,x+1 as first , last  this would end up in infinite loop and hence the break condition

Comment: This code have a bug. Not working for {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};